# Trying to install vim, but encountering error

Tags: bash, vim

I'm trying to install vim using the following code:

```
sudo apt install vim
```

as suggested by -bash when typing in:

```
$ vim
```

However when I type in the first command and tell it that, yes I do want it to install vim, it will go through with it but in the end I get the following error:

```
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Not sure what to do. I'd like to get vim installed in order to write in C, as it was recommended to me. Any help is greatly appreciated.